# Git work flow for apps with common functionality

Tags: android, ios, git, version-control, workflow

I am seeking a solution for setting up a git workflow for our team. We are developing native IOS and Android apps. there will be a master project (for each platform) that will contain all the all the core functionality and then a version of the master will be customized for each customer. We need to make bug fixes and changes to common functionality in the master project and these apply to each customized customer build. Changing each customer copy would be unsustainable. 
I am currently using a branch for each customer and all common functionality is edited in the a "base branch" but this approach seems messy.

**Edit**

the main problem i am having with this is when i make changes to the the template project is i was told to "merge" only specific files i would have to checkout the file from one branch to the others (client branches) but this would then over right client specific changes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could try making your common (master project) files in one git repository and then make a different repo for each customer and in the code, reference to your common repo. Let me know what you think of this.

Comment: @AbhinavNair What do you mean by reference? would i still  be able to pull (proberbly the wrong word) updates from master project?

Comment: I mean like making a library for everything common. Something like what Cocoapods does. But instead of publishing in the pod spec and using it through pods, you use it as a submodule in your client git repository. Then you can add it to the client project. This way all your repositories will also remain private.

Comment: Could you possibly explain your suggestion in some detail. i do not know what you mean by library in this context, and i am not very experienced in git (have only used it for individual projects ) but will look into submodules